# Render custom template into Vue.js render function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can [Vue render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) receive part template from outer?

If there is a render function like bellow:

```
var custom_form_modal = function ( context, custom_form ) {

  context.$Modal.info({
    render: (h) => {
      return h('div', {})
    }
  }）
...
```

the `custem_form` such as like bellow:

```
<Form ref="formValidate" :model="formValidate" :rules="ruleValidate" :label-width="80">
    <FormItem label="Name" prop="name">
        <Input v-model="formValidate.name" placeholder="Enter your name"></Input>
    </FormItem>
    <FormItem label="E-mail" prop="mail">
        <Input v-model="formValidate.mail" placeholder="Enter your e-mail"></Input>
    </FormItem>
    <FormItem label="City" prop="city">
        <Select v-model="formValidate.city" placeholder="Select your city">
            <Option value="beijing">New York</Option>
            <Option value="shanghai">London</Option>
            <Option value="shenzhen">Sydney</Option>
        </Select>
    </FormItem>
</Form>
```

or whatever the javascript-type that can explain as a form.

I want put it as the `custom_form`, and then render into the `div` (you see the `custom_form_modal`).

Is there a way to realize this?

---

**EDIT-1**

I render the template by the function `custom_form_modal`, then I can show the modal in a button click event, then I do not need write code into the invoking vue file's `<template>`. This is my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I read the [document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments), and found the solution to archive it:

```
var custom_form_modal = function (context,  custom_form_component ) {

  context.$Modal.info({
    render: (h) => {
      return h('div', {

      },[
        h(custom_form_component, { props: {} })
      ])
    }
  })
}
```

use the `custom_form_modal` :

```
import custom_form from '../components/combined_table/components/custom_form.vue'

  export default {

    methods: {
      handleStart() {
        Util.custom_form_modal(this, custom_form)
      }
    },
    components: {
      custom_form
    }
  };
```